# Retrofit Http request returns a forbidden field name

Tags: android, retrofit2

Android, Retrofit request returns something like this

```
"image": [{
"size": "small",
"#text":"https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/3b54885952161aaea4ce2965b2db1638.png"
}]
```

I require the size and the #text fields but producing this data class is not allowed i.e.

```
data class Image(
val #text: String,
val size: String)
```

Is there an alternative way to get the #text field

Comment: What library are you using for json deserialisation?

Comment: I'm new to retrofit but im using         addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

Answer (score 2):

```
data class Image(
 @SerializedName("#text") val text: String,
 @SerializedName("size") val size: String)
```

If you are using gson as converter factory in Retrofit.